# git push returns "unknown value given to http.version: 'HTTP/1.1."

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

My github repo started to give me this error when pushing:

**unknown value given to http.version: 'HTTP/1.1.'**

Here is the full log:

```
 % git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
% git push
warning: unknown value given to http.version: 'HTTP/1.1.'
batch response: Unknown HTTP version "HTTP/1.1."                                                          
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/7), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/blabla/unity-blabla.git'
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you use `git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1`?

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen oh, yes. I'm going to remove it from the config to see whether it fixes the issue.

Comment: See my answer below, and let me know if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Do you really have a trailing `.` in the configuration value? What if you remove it?

Comment: @j6t You are right! That might very well be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either open the gitconfig file (`~/.gitconfig` on Unix based systems, and `C:\ProgramData\Git\config` on Windows), and edit the line containing the HTTP version manually (i.e., remove it).

Or, you can type the following command:

```
git config --global --unset http.version
```

Comment: Another way to fix the issue is to simply remove it from the global git config file. I did it and solved the issue.